I designed an Op Amp but the feedback loop would not generate the expected behavior
I have designed the following operational amplifier as my final project of the Analoge Amplifiers subject.

It consists of a differential amplifier as input stage, then there is a common emiter amplifier to get a bigger voltage amplification and the output stage is a type AB push-pull power amplifier.
It has a voltage gain of around 100 and simulation shows no apparent distortion. Everything seems to work just fine.
THE PROBLEM
When I try to implement a feedback circuit with the op amp, like an inverting amplifier for example, I don't get the expected behavior.

When I put a feedback network like shown in the past image the voltage gain should be considerably lower than the open loop gain, but the results I'm getting from the simulation are that the gain gets slightly bigger. :(
I am no expert in design and am struggling to grasp all the concepts involved, so all help and ideas are welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

That's a pretty strange front end. I would kind of expect collectors of Q1/Q3 to go to the two sides of a current mirror rather than being tied together.

The resolution of your image is not good enough to establish some connections (crossing or joined).

Operational Amplifiers by definition have extremely high gain.  Does this not matter here?

The input stage isn't really differential, you have the collectors connected together when they should be separate.
The simplest way is to have a resistor between each collector and the associated supply rail, then take the output from one of the collectors.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A more advanced way is to use a current mirror. Do away with the current source Q7,8 & 9 and try a couple of resistors, once you get it working like that you can try a current mirror and see if that improves the performance.
Also you have to make sure of the inversion through the amplifier, depending on the following stages you might need to take the output from the differential stage from one transistor or the other. The feedback should go to the inverting input which is the transistor that for a more positive signal will give a more negative signal at the output of the amp. Trace through the circuit and see how each stage changes the polarity of the signal. As it is now, it looks like a more positive signal on the base of Q1 will turn it off more, making the collector go more negative, this is connected to the base of Q2, so it will be turned off more and it's collector will go more positive, this then drives the output stage which being emitter followers will keep the polarity the same, so the output goes more positive for a more positive input. That makes Q1 the non-inverting input so the input signal should go to it and the feedback should go to Q3.
